# giving indicates as an argument to a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is possible to rewritte this function

```
def highlight_cells(x):
    df = x.copy()
    df.loc[:,:] = 'background-color: grey' 
    df.iloc[1:3, 1:3] = 'background-color: steelblue'
    return df 

df.style.apply(highlight_cells, axis=None)
```

so that the execution of the function below would have the same effect?

```
def highlight_cells(x, indicates):
    df = x.copy()
    df.loc[:,:] = 'background-color: grey' 
    df.iloc[indicates] = 'background-color: steelblue'
    return df
```

`df.style.apply(highlight_cells, axis=None, indicates=[1:3, 1:3])`

I would like to pass indicates e.g. array as an argument for further operation in a function

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
def highlight_cells(x, idx):
    df = x.copy()
    df.loc[:,:] = 'background-color: grey'
    df.iloc[idx[0]:idx[1], idx[2]:idx[3]] = 'background-color: steelblue'
    print(df)
```

Then you can pass `indicates` array as `indicates=[1,3,1,3]`

Comment: ```idx = pd.IndexSlice
slice_ = idx[idx[1:2, 1:2]]
df.style.apply(highlight_cells, axis=None, subset=slice_)```
I also found a way with pd.index
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html

Comment: Its hard to read here, you can post this as an answer so it may help someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative version of the solution using `pd.IndexSlice`
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Finer-Control-with-Slicing

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
slice_ = idx[idx[1:2, 1:2]]

def highlight_cells(x):
    df = x.copy()
    df.loc[:,:] = 'background-color: steelblue' 
    return df 

df.style.apply(highlight_cells, axis=None, subset=slice_)
```